# Datepicker not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, datepicker

I am developing a Chrome Extension. I tried the below code for datepicker. But it is not working in extension file. Successfully working in a normal html file.

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display inline</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to do the same thing the first thing is that you cant have script in your html file you have to get it from a .js file.
as its not allowed to be written in .html for chrome extension